# How to create mutile horizontal carousel scroll view in android

Tags: android, carousel, horizontal-scrolling

I want to create just like this in picture.
[image]

carousel is a fantastic pattern to show off featured items and relevant new arrivals. For example, new items matching the customer’s last search in their local area would be a sure winner.

I **[followed](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/02/01/android-carousel-design-pattern/)** but could not create just like this,where multiple horizontal carousel.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically inflate ImageViews inside a HorizontalScroll View... The inflated ImageViews has to be of the specified width and height... You can set them either using XML or using a ViewTreeObserver

Hope this solves your problem...